# Need help debugging a function called on click that uses position and crashes on resize

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, window-resize

I have a parent which I read its `position` using jQuery, and assign its `left` to the child. It works when initially loaded but breaks at resize and I'm having difficulties at debugging it. More specifically it's a [flexMenu](https://github.com/352Media/flexMenu).

Whenever the menu is smaller than the width of its parent a "More" button appears and holds the links or buttons that can't fit the parent.

So, this "More" button has a `.flexMenu-viewMore` class assigned, and whenever clicked an `.active` class is added.

What I did was read the `position` of `.active` (class added after "More" is clicked) and assign its `left` to `.flexMenu-popup` (which would be the dropdown-content). Like this:

```
$(".flexMenu-viewMore").click(function(){
  var x = $(".active").position();
  var dropdown_content = $('.flexMenu-popup');
  dropdown_content.css('left',x.left);
});
```

Whenever I clicked "More" again, the `.active` class is removed and then I get a `TypeError: x is undefined`. Of course, because there is no `.active` class anywhere in the document.

So I added and if so that `x` is only defined if `.active` exist.

```
var demo = document.getElementsByClassName('active').length;
if ( demo > 0 ) {
  var x = $(".active").position();
  var dropdown_content = $('.flexMenu-popup');
  dropdown_content.css('left',x.left);
}
```

I no longer get the Typerror but, my script keeps working *only* after the first load. Whenever I resize it, it won't work (even if the more doesn't "absorb" any more links).

How could I make use of something like

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  // Code goes here
});
```

Since, in reality, I only want to call it whenever `.flexMenu-viewMore` is clicked ("More" button).

Does position breaks at resize and I'm not aware of it?
How could I proceed to debug this?

Comment: One warning I'll give you is that you want to try desperately to keep your styling in the css and not the javascript.

Comment: @nurdyguy I know! JS is like my go to when all my attempts at CSS failed

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the position?  Can you post some of the html?

Comment: What problem are you having when putting the code in your resize handler?